# PHP Curl error 60 querying reCAPTCHA API

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

I have a PHP site that queries several APIs via HTTPS. All work, except for reCAPTCHA. This produces the following error:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

A common solution to this problem is to download a .pem file from the curl site and add it to the PHP.ini file, which I did:

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo="/var/www/cacert.pem"

[openssl]
; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may still
; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
; option.
openssl.cafile="/var/www/cacert.pem"
```

The error still happens. If I check `phpinfo()` the curl property is not set, but the openssl property is:
[image: PHPinfo file]
[image: PHPinfo file]

I have restarted php-fpm and hard rebooted the server to no avail. There are no relevant errors in the startup log.

I am using PHP Version `7.2.4-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by upgrading OpenSSL to the latest version, `OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018`.